# Find a word in Column A and give abbreviation in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

Sample data:
[image]
[image]

```vb
Sub DDword()
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim cellValueA As String
    Dim cellValue1 As String, cellValue2 As String
    Dim words1 As Variant, words2 As Variant
    Dim wordIndex As Long
    Dim word As String
    Dim dword As Variant
    
    Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    lastRow1 = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row of data in Sheet1 column A
    For i = 1 To lastRow1
        ' Get the value in Sheet1 column A for the current row
        cellValue1 = sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        ' Split the string into words
        words1 = Split(cellValue1, " ")
        
        ' Loop through each row of data in Sheet2 column A
        For j = 1 To lastRow2
            ' Get the value in Sheet2 column A for the current row
            cellValue2 = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value

            ' Split the string into words
            words2 = Split(cellValue2, " ")

            ' Loop through each word in Sheet1 column A
            For wordIndex = 0 To UBound(words1)
                ' If the word is found in Sheet2 column A, copy the value in Sheet2 column B to Sheet1 column B
                If InStr(cellValue2, words1(wordIndex)) > 0 Then
                
                    word = words1(wordIndex)
                    ' Copy the value in Sheet2 column B to Sheet1 column B
                    sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value

                End If
            Next wordIndex
         
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried reading column A from sheet1 and column A from sheet2 (attached in images) loop through each word in both columns. If it matches with word I paste column B values from sheet2 to sheet1 column B. It is not 100% accurate.

Comment: why not use `Replace()` ?

Comment: Welcome. VBA is overkill for this. Use XLOOKUP + TEXTJOIN or Power Query instead.

Comment: If you have 4 words in Sheet1 Column A, do you want to find a match for all words, or any of the words?

Comment: If the words in Sheet1 Column A match more than 1 cell in Sheet2, how do you determine which match to use? For example, you have OZ in Sheet1. Do you want to match "OUNCES", or "OUNCES, DRIVING UNDER INFLUENCE"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a formula you can put in B1 on Sheet1, then drag it down:

```
=LET(
    words, TEXTSPLIT(A1, , " "),
    results, MAP(
        words,
        LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP(x, Sheet2!A:A, Sheet2!B:B, ""))
    ),
    TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, results)
)
```

"words" splits the input text on the space character, giving an array of words in the data.

"results" applies XLOOKUP against each word in "words". It looks to see if that word exists in column A of Sheet2. If it does, it returns whatever is in column B of Sheet2. "results" is then an array of either a word from column B of Sheet2, or an empty string.

TEXTJOIN then takes this "results" array and joins them with a comma.

[image]

Comment: In what way? What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: world 2016 formula showing as error

Comment: Ok, then I recommend exploring Power Query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few remarks

- Split words2 and not use later
- Use string comparison
- Where the **word** variable is used
- There are declared variables not in use

So try

```
InStr(1,cellValue2, words1(wordIndex),1)
```

It overwrites the sheet1 cell if find more matches, so try

```
sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & Sheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value
```

For inserting the comma, add this line

```
If sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value<> Empty Then sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value & ","
word = words1(wordIndex)
```